# How do I find the source file for a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I know you can view all possible rake tasks by typing

```
rake -T
```

But I need to know what exactly a task does.  From the output, how can I find a source file that actually has the task?  For example, I'm trying to find the source for the db:schema:dump task.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Despite what others have said, you *can* programmatically get the source location of rake tasks in a rails application.  To do this, just run something like the following in your code or from a console:

```
# load all the tasks associated with the rails app
Rails.application.load_tasks

# get the source locations of actions called by a task
task_name = 'db:schema:load' # fully scoped task name
Rake.application[task_name].actions.map(&:source_location)
```

This will return the source locations of any code that gets executed for this task.  You can also use `#prerequisites` instead of `#source_location` to get a list of prerequisite task names (e.g. 'environment', etc).

You can also list all tasks loaded using:

```
Rake.application.tasks
```

**UPDATE:** See Magne's good answer below. For versions of **rake >= 0.9.0** you can use `rake -W` to show the source location of your rake tasks.

Comment: Just FYI: you have to make sure that rake is loaded before you use this method.  if it is not, simply do a "require 'rake'".

Comment: much obliged, kind sir!

Comment: Nice man! You remember how did you find it out? I was getting stuck inside rake itself for task `assets:environment`, which thanks to your solution now I know resides in `railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:445`. The `rake -W` was a dead end.

Answer (score 95):

I know this is an old question, but in any case:

```
rake -W
```

This was introduced in rake 0.9.0.

http://rake.rubyforge.org/doc/release_notes/rake-0_9_0_rdoc.html

> Support for the –where (-W) flag for showing where a task is defined.

Comment: Thanks for updating this, always nice to get a more current answer!

Comment: Wow, why I didn't know it earlier! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

There is no programmatic way to do this unfortunately.  Rake tasks can be loaded either from rails itself, lib/tasks, or from any plugin with a tasks directory.

This should nab most everything not within Rails itself:

```
find . -name "*.rake" | xargs grep "whatever"
```

As for `db:schema:dump`, here's the source:

```
desc "Create a db/schema.rb file that can be portably used against any DB supported by AR"
task :dump => :environment do
  require 'active_record/schema_dumper'
  File.open(ENV['SCHEMA'] || "#{RAILS_ROOT}/db/schema.rb", "w") do |file|
    ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump(ActiveRecord::Base.connection, file)
  end
end
```

It can be found on line 242 of lib/tasks/database.rake in the rails 2.2.2 gem.  If you've got a different version of Rails, just search for "`namespace :schema`".

You probably actually want the source of the `ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper`, but I think you should have no trouble figuring out where that is.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

For most rake tasks in Rails, look in the Rails gem directory, in lib/tasks.

If you've vendored Rails into your app directory structure then look in vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks instead

Either way, db:schema:dump is in databases.rake.

Comment: But is there a programmatic way to do this?  I ended up doing a find in file search.