# Where are rake tasks defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rakefile

On a freshly created Rails project (generated by `rails someName`), one can run some 'default' rake tasks like:

- `rake test`
- `rake db:migrate`
- etc

Question is, where does these tasks get described? The default `Rakefile` doesn't have all these tasks.

Furthermore, I checked out some project that uses `rspec` and I am able to run `rake spec` to run all the tests. Where does the `spec` target defined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the source file for a rake task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830423/how-do-i-find-the-source-file-for-a-rake-task)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Rake tasks are automatically loaded from the folder structure `lib/tasks/*.rake`

When we are talking about the task db:migrate for example, it is located within the rails gem in `lib/tasks/databases.rake`

So for a specific project, you will always have the tasks within the project folder structure as well as all tasks within the specified gems.

Comment: At least in Rails 4, the database tasks are stored in the ActiveRecord gem. To see the path Rake loads a task from, use `rake -W task:name`

Answer (score 121):

If by described you mean defined, rake -W is your friend. Example:

```
$ rake -W db:create
```

=>

```
rake db:create  /path/to/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:39:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Just found this out today :)

Answer (score 24):

To find the specific files and line numbers where a task is defined and/or modified, do this:

Start a rails console:

```
rails c
```

Then run these commands:

```
require 'rake'
Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata=true
Rake.application.load_rakefile
tsk = Rake.application.tasks.find {|t| t.name =='my_task_name'}
tsk.locations
```

Rake basically can track the locations internally and has a nifty method to show them upon request.  The above code basically loads rake, tells Rake to track the file locations, loads the Rakefile (and all other included ones), finds the task in question, and calls the locations method on it.

From sameers comment, for rake v 10.1.0 and possibly older versions of rake you might have to call:
    tsk.actions
instead of
    tsk.locations

Comment: This is a great tip! I am working on an application with tasks defined in several different libraries, and it can be really tough to figure out what task comes from where without a trick like this.

Comment: That might be code that works for an older version of Rake ... I have 10.1.0, in which you have to change the last line to `tsk.actions`

Comment: @sameers - Thanks for the comment.  I just tried with rake-10.1.1 and it works with locations.

Comment: I apologize - I should have said "*different* version of," rather than assuming it was an older one :)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I will add something to the main post about it.  Cheers!

Comment: Small note: You shouldn't need that each. `Rake.application.tasks.find`. Also you may need to send load if it's private for you. `Rake.application.send(:load, 'Rakefile')` or you could just use `Rake.application.load_rakefile`.

Comment: @con-- Thanks for that.  Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify which version of rails you're using but in 3.0.7 the `db` tasks are located in the ActiveRecord gem in

```
lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake
```

#### Update:

As of rails version 3.2.7, the tasks are still where I stated above.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3 the `railties` gem defines a lot of rake tasks.

```
railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/tasks/annotations.rake
railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake
railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/tasks/engine.rake
railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/tasks/framework.rake
railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/tasks/log.rake
railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/tasks/middleware.rake
railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/tasks/misc.rake
railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake
railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/tasks/statistics.rake
railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/tasks/tmp.rake
railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake
```

If your `$EDITOR` is configured, you can easily see them yourself with the `open_gem` gem:

```
gem install open_gem
gem open railties
```

Answer (score 2):

To list all tasks:

```
rake -P
```

Since many tasks come from gems you install it's hard to know which ones are added...

Comment: `rails --help` might help show some of the tasks that rake doesn't: guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails

Answer (score 1):

The project you checked out probably uses the **rspec-rails** gem.  That gem defines the `spec` task.  You can see the source code for it here:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake