# How do you add a folder to rake stats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I've added some folders (lib, spec, cells, etc.) to my Rails app and would like to add them to the rake stats list. Is it possible to add new folders?

Comment: You're correct, lib is being included (not sure why I included it). I do still have some other folders I'd like to include. Factories for example, cells (http://cells.rubyforge.org/), and a few others. Is it possible to specify the folders you want tracked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an excellent answer to find where [a specific rake task is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12226128/429758).

With that tip, found that the `rake stats` task is defined in `gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/tasks/statistics.rake` file; so it is in the `railties gem` which is part of the [rails repository](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks/statistics.rake).

At the very top of the file, the directories to be considered are included in the `STATS_DIRECTORIES` variable.

Probably best to [implement a custom rake task](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks) - named `my_stats` for example - with the same code, and add the new folders that you want to include.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Unfortunately you can't specify customer file types to track. The Rails master added support for .js and .coffee but theres no way to track anything else. That hasn't made it into the 3.2 branch yet (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/code_statistics.rb).

Answer (score 15):

I know I'm late to the party, but as I did not find more information, I'm adding my answer into the mix.

I've added a rake-task to my project with content similar to the following:

```
task :stats => "todolist:statsetup"

namespace :todolist do
  task :statsetup do
    require 'rails/code_statistics'
    ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ["Policies", "app/policies"]
    ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ["Services", "app/services"]

    # For test folders not defined in CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES (ie: spec/)
    ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ["Services specs", "specs/services"]
    CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Services specs"
  end
end
```

This added both folders to my `rake stats`

Comment: Worked perfectly for me (tested in Rails 4). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found it useful to insert new stats at a sensible position in the list.

Here's what I'm using (with rails 5.1):

```
# lib/stats.rake

require "rails/code_statistics"

task stats: :more_stats

task :more_stats do
  %w[Forms Policies Presenters Serializers Services].each_with_index do |type, i|
    STATS_DIRECTORIES.insert i + 5, [type, "app/#{type.downcase}"]
    STATS_DIRECTORIES.insert i * 2 + 13, ["#{type} tests", "test/#{type.downcase}"]
    CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "#{type} tests"
  end
end
```